Converting CID into Chembl_id using pubchempy
I'm currently working on a project in python, a fairly long step is to convert a list of CIDs (Compound Identification Numbers) into Chembl_id . For that im using the pubchempy lib
from pubchempy import Compound
chembl_values=[]
for cid in cids:
    c = Compound.from_cid(cid)
    find=c.synonyms
    chembl_values.append(next((value for value in find if value.startswith('CHEMBL')), None))
chembl_values = [value for value in chembl_values if value is not None]

(the last step is for removing the CID that doesnt have a Chembl_id)
With this code I obtain various data, then "skim" it and keep only the chembl_id   I also tried to do this with Request but I can't get just the Chembl_id.
I would like to try to optimize the code in terms of time because now for only 170 cid it takes an average of 3 minutes.
Do you have any ideas on how to optimize the code so as to make the whole process faster? maybe using the pubchem library differently or using Request differently

Could you phrase this more like a question?

It depends on what you want to do and the specifics of it.
For faster results you could turn the for loop into a list comprehension.
from pubchempy import Compound
chembl_values = [
    value
    for cid in cids
    for value in Compound.from_cid(cid).synonyms
    if value.startswith('CHEMBL')
]

Other solution might be implementing an async function.
import aiohttp
import asyncio
from pubchempy import Compound

async def fetch_synonyms(session, cid):
    try:
        c = await asyncio.to_thread(Compound.from_cid, cid)  # Fetch compound data asynchronously
        synonyms = c.synonyms
        # Return the first CHEMBL synonym, or None if not found
        return next((value for value in synonyms if value.startswith('CHEMBL')), None)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error fetching CID {cid}: {e}")
        return None

async def process_cids(cids):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        # Fetch synonyms for all CIDs asynchronously
        tasks = [fetch_synonyms(session, cid) for cid in cids]
        chembl_values = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    return [value for value in chembl_values if value is not None]

